# Do jq's variable bindings work through functions?

Tags: variables, scope, global-variables, jq

I have the following script for [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/):

```
$ jq -n 'def f: $a; 1 as $a | $a'
1
```

Since `f` is not used, this outputs `1` as expected.  However:

```
$ jq -n 'def f: $a; 1 as $a | f'
jq: error: a/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
def f: $a; 1 as $a | f
jq: 1 compile error
```

Is it not possible to use variable bindings through functions?

Answer (score 0):

In jq, the scoping of variables is defined lexically. With `f` defined as `$a`, `f` can only be evaluated as `$a` if `$a` is "visible" to `f`.  This can be achieved, for example, using one of the command-line options such as —arg or —argjson.

It can also be achieved as illustrated by:

```
jq -n '2 as $a | def f: $a; f'
```

Note also that lexical scoping works with sub-functions as well:

```
def f($a): def g: $a; g;
f(1)
```

yields:

```
1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand. From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Advancedfeatures), it says that _"Both are scoped lexically, with expressions being able to refer only to symbols that have been defined “to the left” of them."_ In my example, is `$a` not "to the left" of `f`? I bind 1 to `$a` (the left) then use it in `f` (to the right).

Comment: "To the left" is in quotation marks for a reason.  It's not an attempt to define lexical scoping, just a kind of mnemonic.  Lexical scoping is the operative phrase.